# Reference for the trig identities $\cos\phi= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\phi}}$ and $\sin\phi=\frac{\tan\phi}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\phi}}$?

Tags: trigonometry

What reference has the trigonometric identities below?

$$\begin{align}
\cos\phi &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2\phi}} \\
\sin\phi &= \frac{\tan\phi}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2\phi}}
\end{align}$$

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "origin/reference"? Are you asking how or who first discovered them, or something else like that?

Comment: Hello @JohnOmiela no am not looking for who discover it, am looking for a reference that those two identities are available in...

Comment: There are quite a few trigonometric identities, but I don't know off hand where the $2$ you list are given in a reference source, e.g., online page, book, etc. However, note the first identity is fairly easy to prove (although actually the RHS should $\pm$) and the second one follows by multiplying both sides of the first one by $\tan(φ)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Pythagorean_identities

Comment: Or, more generally, https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=trigonometric+identities .

Comment: @XanderHenderson  I just noticed that reference in Wikipedia when you wrote your comment.

Comment: @aows61: Are you looking for an authoritative explanation of how the identities are derived? Or do you just want a source you can cite in a paper or something?

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan , am looking for a reference ( book, authorized website, .....etc) that have both of the written identities.

Comment: Thanks indeed @XanderHenderson , do you have more resources other than wikipedia?

Comment: @Blue you are right, am looking for a source the have those two identities just to make sure they are exist in a reference.

Comment: @aows61 I don't understand what it is that you want.  The second link that I provided is a simple Google search for "trigonometric identities"---you will likely find *hundreds* of references via that search.  Or read nearly any American precalculus or trigonometry text.  Or simply derive the require identities from the Pythagorean theorem and the definitions of $\sin$, $\cos$, and $\tan$.

Comment: dear @XanderHenderson 
am searching as well, but if you know a good reference that have both of the identities exactly,kindly, share its name with me...

Comment: Very mild point of clarrification but 

$$ \cos(\theta) = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\theta)}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\theta)}} $$

Comment: For anyone downvoting, let's not forget that he's a new member and English is clearly not his first language.

Comment: @KevinNivek thanks dear Kevin, but am looking for a good reference that have those two identities...

Comment: @aows61 - Yes, I'm trying to help you. If it's downvoted enough then the question will be closed and you won't be able to get an answer. That's why it's important to remind people of your situation.

Comment: @KevinNivek A downvote is not a personal attack against a person or their lack of English proficiency.  As per the hovertext on the downvote button, a downvote means that the downvoter(s) find the question to show a lack of research, to be unclear, or to be "not useful".  A downvote is about the appropriateness of a *question* for MSE.

Comment: Hello @KevinNivek , if you could wrote a reference for the above two identities, wouldn’t be better than a discussion about who and how many downvote/upvote???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already know the identity $\sin^2 \phi + \cos^2 \phi = 1$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\phi)}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\sin^2 
\phi}{\cos^2\phi}}}\end{align*}\\ 
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\phi}{\cos^2\phi}+\frac{\sin^2 
\phi}{\cos^2\phi}}}\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2\phi + \sin^2 
\phi}{\cos^2\phi}}}\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2\phi}}}\\
= \cos{\phi}
$$

Also, then we have $\frac{\tan \phi}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\phi)}} = \tan\phi \cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2{\phi}}} =  \tan{\phi}\cdot\cos{\phi} = \frac{\sin\phi}{\cos\phi}\cos\phi = \sin\phi.$

Comment: Be careful about signs!

Comment: very helpful and clear way of derivation @user326210 
Am looking for a good reference that have both of the identities, if you know a good reference (book, authorized website,....etc) kindly, share with us...

Answer (score 2):

I have no reference, but a derivation is that in the first quadrant is $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\phi)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{\sin^2(\phi)}{\cos^2(\phi)}}} = \sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(\phi)}{\sin^2(\phi) + \cos^2(\phi)}} = \cos(\phi)$$ and then $$ \frac{\tan(\phi)}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\phi)}} = \tan(\phi) \cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2(\phi)}} = \tan(\phi) \cos(\phi) = \frac{\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\phi)} \cdot \cos(\phi) = \sin(\phi) $$ It's also worth noting that the question as stated isn't careful about signs. I've presumed that to fix this we could fix our domain to the first quadrant, but you could also do the casework, taking the equality in absolute values, to use this in other regions of the unit circle as well.

Comment: Be careful about signs!

Comment: Can't thank you enough for your derivations @Cade Reinberger , 
Am also looking for a reference that have those two identities, if you know a  good reference, kindly, share with us...